# How to get client IP address only in Django under nginx?

Tags: django, nginx

Hi i am trying to get the client IP address in django. My webserver is Nginx. so i am doing this in my nginx conf

fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;

fastcgi_param X_FORWADRD_FOR $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

The problem is i have 4 server under a loadbalancer and when i call a site using a domain i get the ip of the server when using this(client_ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']). But when i call the site using the ip address i get the client ip only

And when i use this (client_ip = request.META['X_FORWARDED_FOR']) i get the client ip and the ip of the server

How do i just get the Client ip alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now what i have done is

```
ipaddress = request.META['X_FORWADRD_FOR']

ipaddress = ipaddress.split(",")

ip_address = ipaddress[0]
```

to get the client ip alone

Answer (score -1):

You could reintegrate [the SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor middleware that was removed in Django 1.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/releases/1.1/#removed-setremoteaddrfromforwardedfor-middleware). This will dynamically reset `request.META["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to the client IP address.